# C# ASP.NET Webform Image Source from different directory

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Currently, I can just use the following just fine: `<img src="Images/abc.jpg" />`

The file above is actually in the following path:

> D:\proj\capp\capp\Images

However, I would like to access image from:

> D:\proj\capp\Images

How do I access it? I tried putting direct path to the `src` tag to no avail.

Comment: Which is the root folder of your web application?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access an image located **within** your web-app root this following is the  correct way.

```
<img src="Images/abc.jpg" />
```

but if you want to access an image outside of your app-root you need a fully qulified url **(website.com/image.jpg)** and you **cannot access** a physical path exist outside of your app-root and also it's **not recommended** to do so.